# Powerline speed difference

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I have 200Mbp/s that I receive from my provider and my PC is far from the router so to counter that problem I'm using a powerline adapter so I have a wired connection, The powerline adapter gives on my PC a speed of around 15Mbp/s to 30Mbp/s

Which is pretty weird as I should be receiving a higher speed and I need to know if using a powerline adapter will make a difference in speed the one I am using is [TP-Link AV500](https://www.tp-link.com/la/products/details/cat-18_TL-PA4010-KIT.html)

The speed test for reference [Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net/result/7470446521)

Comment: use `iperf` or copy a shared file to check your LAN speed first. It should be higher than the internet speed. Also check if the powerline connection crosses any circuit breakers or not?

Comment: unplug as many things as possible, reboot the power line adapter.  Test, and re-test as you plug each device back in to see if any of them are affecting your speeds.  The power line device may/may not only negotiate the speed during start up, and if that is the case unplugging and replugging the power line adapters each time maybe necessary.

Comment: Power line adapters have to deal with a lot of interference which causes quite a speed decrease. It’s convenient but you pay the price of bandwidth. If you have the adapters plugged into the wall, and not a surge protector, the speed you’re seeing is probably what you will get. I’ve personally never had one go over 45 Mbps.

Answer (score 3):

Powerline speed will depend a lot on the wiring of your house/flat. You are transmitting data over a medium that was not meant for it, so you shouldn't be "receiving a higher speed" - the powerline adapter does the best it can given the circumstances.

From my own house I know that speed goes down drastically over greater distances, and it also makes a difference if both adapters are connected to the same electrical phase out of the three phases you have (assuming you live in a country where that's also the case), or a different one.

If you absolutely require a greater speed, consider installing a Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of a powerline adapter is dependant on its noise immunity, and what the adapters max speed actually is. I believe it's normal for these (unless in a perfect environment) to **not** reach the theoretical speed.

It may help if you ensure that these adapters are on the **same** branch circuit coming from the breaker. (The two powerline adapters shouldn't cross breakers.)

One of the things I noticed is this. Those devices are advertised as being 500Mbps. **That** speed, or the speed from your **ISP** will never be possible. Under the hardware specification section of the link you provided, you will find "1*10/100Mbps Ethernet Port".

So the max you would have ever received was 100Mbps. And actual real world conditions with noise is usually considerably less.

I must admit that 15Mbps seems extremely slow for these though.